# What Gas Law does one get from a Lennard-Jones Potential

Tags: statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry

Given a potential, at low density we can approximate high order potentials as a sum of two-particle potentials. Given such an approximation, using a Lennard-Jones 6-12 potential, one can obtain a full Virial expansion by computing each virial coefficient as a sum of  of certain Mayer cluster integrals over a certain class of graphs on $i+1$ vertices, as one can easily find many resources for, say [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_coefficient).

But, in particular, I wonder what sort of analytic work one can do into a full virial expansion for a Lennard-Jones Potential. That is, it seems like it'd be really cool to know what happens as we take this calculation to arbitrary high order, and finally infinite order,  virial expansion, do those calculations result in, perhaps, some miraculous simplification, or perhaps likelier, with some clever thoughts can some sort of gas law be stated in the form of some nested series and/or integrals?

If you know of a reference, or a result, or have an idea, I would really like how this calculation works out, or even how one would go about it.